# How /var/lib/dpkg/lock works?

Tags: dpkg, lock

/var/lib/dpkg/lock is file that holding a lock when "A package manager is working". But how this system works? I have /var/lib/dpkg/lock everytime when I have Linux working. When I use one of package manager for dpkg I have it without any change. So I can't see it in action.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know for certain, but this is most likely implemented via `flock()`. The `flock()` system call creates an advisory lock on a file. If another application tries to attain a lock on the file, the kernel will block until the original lock is gone, or return `EWOULDBLOCK` if the `LOCK_NB` option is given. This locking mechanism would allow the lock file to be used without deleting and re-creating it.

Update: Checked the source and verified that it is advisory locking, but it doesn't use `flock()` directly. `fcntl` is used:

enquiry.c:

```
        if (modstatdb_is_locked())
          puts(_(
"Another process has locked the database for writing, and might currently be\n"
"modifying it, some of the following problems might just be due to that.\n"));
        head_running = true;
      }
```

dbmodify.c:

```
modstatdb_is_locked(void)
{
  int lockfd;
  bool locked;

  if (dblockfd == -1) {
    lockfd = open(lockfile, O_RDONLY);
    if (lockfd == -1)
      ohshite(_("unable to open lock file %s for testing"), lockfile);
  } else {
    lockfd = dblockfd;
  }

  locked = file_is_locked(lockfd, lockfile);

  /* We only close the file if there was no lock open, otherwise we would
   * release the existing lock on close. */
  if (dblockfd == -1)
    close(lockfd);

  return locked;
}
```

file.c:

```
file_is_locked(int lockfd, const char *filename)
{
    struct flock fl;

    file_lock_setup(&fl, F_WRLCK);

    if (fcntl(lockfd, F_GETLK, &fl) == -1)
        ohshit(_("unable to check file '%s' lock status"), filename);

    if (fl.l_type == F_WRLCK && fl.l_pid != getpid())
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

dpkg.h:

```
#define LOCKFILE          "lock"
```

From the `fcntl` manpage:

```
   Advisory locking
       F_GETLK,  F_SETLK  and  F_SETLKW  are  used to acquire, release, and test for the existence of record locks (also known as file-segment or file-region locks).  The third
       argument, lock, is a pointer to a structure that has at least the following fields (in unspecified order).
```

Comment: I tried this but it seems to not be the case. I manually grabbed an exclusive lock on the file, but dpkg still operated normally.

Comment: @Patrick I can see in the source code that it does in fact call `flock()` on the lock file in `dbmodify.c`.

Comment: @patrick lockfile is "lock", not the database.

Comment: then why does `flock -x /var/lib/dpkg/lock dpkg -r somepackage` work?

Comment: @Patrick a lock doesn't stick around after the caller process exits.

Comment: what's that got to do with it?

Comment: I do not understand why `flock` does not lock the file like `synaptic`; when I use the latter, `apt update` does not finish successfully: "E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)". I want to lock database while I select pkgs from a list and then remove those packages.

Comment: @Patrick: flock uses a different type of lock; see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`dpkg` has always used [`fcntl(2)`](https://manpages.debian.org/fcntl.2) advisory record locks. This means the locks are associated with a process, and thus the lock files **must** never be removed, or they might cause database or filesystem damage due to possibly two or more `dpkg` instanced ending running concurrently.

It is **always** preferable to kill a running `dpkg` instance if that ends up being required (because `dpkg` is supposed to be resilient against sudden entire system crashes and abrupt termination, and problems arising from that would be considered serious bugs in need of fixing), than ever considering removing the lock files.

This is documented in the [dpkg frontend spec](https://git.dpkg.org/cgit/dpkg/dpkg.git/tree/doc/spec/frontend-api.txt), and in the [dpkg FAQ](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_What_can_be_done_when_the_dpkg_lock_is_held.3F).

Answer (score 0):

As I see, *dpkg* locks the file `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` using *lockf*(3), which in turn uses *fcntl*(2).

```
$ sudo strace dpkg -r somepackage 2>&1 |
> grep F_SETLKW
fcntl64(5, F_SETLKW64, {l_type=F_WRLCK, l_whence=SEEK_SET, l_start=0, l_len=0}) = 0
```

This means that you cannot lock the file from the shell using *flock*(1), because this calls *flock*(2), which in many systems doesn't interact with *fnctl* locks.

```
$ sudo strace flock -x /var/lib/dpkg/lock 2>&1 |
> grep 'flock('
flock(3, LOCK_EX)
```

You can however lock the file with the [with-lock-ex](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/with-lock-ex.1.html) program or [this Python script](https://gist.github.com/dspinellis/eb924c195206f57e896d026dbe14befa), both of which acquire a compatible lock.

Comment: AFAIK dpkg has never used lockf(3), at least from its VCS history, the first commit recorded there was already using fcntl(2). While this distinction is indeed immaterial on at least GNU/Linux, assuming that lockf(3) will use fnctl(2) underneath or will use compatible locks is not a safe and portable assumption to make.