# When exactly does dpkg start and stop being locked?

Tags: debian, dpkg

I'm wondering specifically if it remains locked when only installing one package, and running its postinst.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dpkg` places a file lock on `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` when a package management process starts and only removes the lock when the package management process ends.

Please review the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/dpkg) on `dpkg` and the `dpkg` [manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/dpkg.1.html) for more information on `dpkg` itself. I will also include a link to [dpkg.org](https://www.dpkg.org/) which has more specific documentation on the API and file handling of `dpkg`.

There is also [this related stack exchange post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71716/how-var-lib-dpkg-lock-works) discussing how `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` works.

As explained in this post when `dpkg` is used, by either a frontend or `dpkg` itself, a system call `fcntl` is called that places an advisory lock. `dpkg` needs to be able to place this lock and returns `false` and is unable to proceed if this lock is already in place. Once the functions of `dpkg` are complete it releases the hold on `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` freeing up another process to be able to use `dpkg`.

Importantly, when you receive a warning that there is a lock on `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` you need to not delete this file but figure out whether there is already a user or process (such as one started by `unattended-upgrades`) that is currently running a package management process. This process might be hung so you will have to kill it and recover from potential database corruption. This would be completed by following the advice in this [related post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process). I would again caution that deleting the file is not the best way to remove the lock. You need to end the rogue process and potentially repair `dpkg` if you continue to have issues.

To get to your specific question of:

> ...if it remains locked when only installing one package, and running its postinst.

`dpkg` should only be locked when completing package management processes. A postinst script would likely fall under a package management process, however if it is falling to release `/var/lib/dpkg/lock` or its variants then that is an issue that should be brought up with the package maintainer(s).

Comment: Thanks! I've added an answer to the "How /var/lib/dpkg/lock works" spelling out clearly the behavior, and clarified the [dpkg FAQ entry](https://wiki.debian.org/Teams/Dpkg/FAQ#Q:_What_can_be_done_when_the_dpkg_lock_is_held.3F) that talks about this too. Although I'd appreciate if you could either remove or explicitly mention that the Ubuntu post is all wrong, as even the answer that mentions killing processes, only recommends so instead of the other broken methods. :) It might also be worth using "release" instead of "remove" when talking about the lock to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Oh and newer `dpkg` and `apt` versions print way more verbose information about removal not being the correct solution, and if possible printing the `PID` or process name for the other process holding the lock, so that should help with this perennial question.